# Why can't ArUco3Detection find these tags?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, detection, aruco

I created a custom 4x4 dictionary, and put four of them on a circuit board into the silkscreen.

[image]

```
myDict = cv2.aruco.custom_dictionary(4, 4, 1337)
```

I am using cv2.aruco in python, and just calling `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` with arguments for `image` and `dictionary` (and no argument for `parameters`, thus leaving them default) works just fine.

```
corners, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(frame, myDict)
```

However, ArUco3Detection (a parameter I can pass) is much faster.  I would rather use that, as I have a lot of frames of video to parse.

When I try to do so, however, it fails to find the tags!  I have messed with practically every setting, and can't figure out why this is happening.

```
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
parameters.useAruco3Detection = True
corners, ids, rejected = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(frame, myDict, parameters = parameters)
```

I can see that it's finding squares/contours, and they're showing up in the `rejected` return value.

[image]

Note: Since the ArUco tag is supposed to be black on white, I made a white border around it in the silkscreen on the PCB.  The square the detector is finding encompases that white border, rather than selecting only the inside of it.  I thought perhaps I could try setting `markerBorderBits` to `2` and `maxErroneousBitsInBorderRate` to `1.0` to counter this, but it didn't work.  Fiddling with other parameters, I have managed to get it to select the inner square, but it still didn't decode.

Suggestions?

Comment: quad detection grabs the white border too? strange! that shouldn't happen. do you invert any picture at any time, or threshold it? aruco should be given the plain camera image itself. try this with a non-custom dictionary, and markers that have a comfortable amount of quiet zone (white border), at least one "module" wide (to use QR terminology). best try this on a model picture (drawn marker), not a camera picture. that's how I would debug this. please review [mre], which includes advice for debugging issues in general.

Comment: OpenCV's aruco received severe "remodeling", including some breaking changes, over the last half year. stuff could have broken for your situation. keep that in mind and don't discount the possibility that it *might not be* an issue with *your* code.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Unfortunately I can't easily (cheaply) produce another PCB with a new set of markers for testing.  I will say that in some situations the Aruco3Detection DOES pick these up properly (I have another camera it works on most of the time).  There's no inverting or thresholding, the image you see is exactly what I pass in.

Comment: produce a sheet of paper with ink/toner on it for testing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ah, that's fair!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I do have a working example that the detector does pick up, I just can't figure out why this one doesn't work.  I was hoping there might be some logs or I could follow a trace, but I don't know if python openCV is built for that.

Comment: I don't think the aruco module can be made more talkative. you can dig around in its source. it was moved from contrib to main repo for the recent v4.7.0 release, just so you know where to look. if you're prepared to build OpenCV yourself, you can litter the code with as much `cout << ...` or printf as you like. OpenCV has facilities for info/warn/error "log" output but I'm not familiar with using that.